# Push notification not receive when Re-login after logout using FCM

Tags: android

I don't get the FCM push notification when I logout in my android app.
The first time I login FCM works fine but after I logout and re-login it would not work. But if I re-login again it works fine. I couldn't find any help.

Detail:

1. First Login FCM work Ok.
2. Logout and re-login FCM push notification would not work.
3. Again Logout and re-login also work fine.

Logout Code:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
```

Comment: Have you update fcm on login ?

Comment: @MuhammadMustafa Yes, i did it but still can't received.